# Can Json.NET serialize to stream with Formatting?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

When using Json.NET library, you can specify formatting when you are serialising to string, but I can't find this option when serialising directly to stream. Am I missing something?

The code for the two serialisation methods is as follows:

```
public static string Serialize(MyObject obj)
{
    JsonSerializerSettings settings = GetJsonSerializerSettings();
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented, settings);
}

public static void SerializeToStream(MyObject obj, Stream stream)
{
    var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(GetJsonSerializerSettings());

    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
    using (var jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(jsonTextWriter, obj);
    }
}

private static JsonSerializerSettings GetJsonSerializerSettings()
{
    JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        Converters = new List<JsonConverter>
        {
            new StringEnumConverter()
        }
    };
    return settings;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but I'd expect it to be fine if you specify the formatting in the settings:

```
public static void SerializeToStream(MyObject obj, Stream stream)
{
    var settings = GetJsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(settings);

    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
    using (var jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(jsonTextWriter, obj);
    }
}
```

(Or change `GetJsonSerializerSettings` in a similar way, of course.)

Comment: Hi there! Just curious why you made this method `static`. Thanks!

Comment: @8protons: Well why wouldn't you want it to be static? It doesn't need to access any instance state, and it's not implementing an interface or anything like that where inheritance is useful.

Comment: _"Well why wouldn't you want it to be static?"_... Why the rhetorical question? I was asking because I didn't know. Wasn't coming at you to question your authority on the topic.

Comment: @8protons: If I'd made it an instance method instead, would you have asked then? (In fact, its static in the question - I probably just copied that.) It just seemed an odd question to me.